# How to select a SpriteViewable (change svg url to highlightedUrl) via code?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-data-visualization

Environment: JS client side.

I have some issues made with Data Visualization SpriteViewables in my model, and the selection works, changing the svg url to the `highlightedUrl`, example:

[image: example selected issue]

In my application, I have an issues list like this:

[image: issues list]

I want that on click in an issue in this list, select the current sprite issue in model (changing the svg url to the `highlightedUrl`), I already have an auxiliary list containing all sprites `dbIds` and `issue.id`, with this list I have the relation between the clicked issue on the list (second image) and the sprite in model.

Having a closer look into the viewable data in data visualization, the Sprite Viewable object doesn't have a key like 'currentUrl' to change:

[image]

So it has to be another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting/clicking on a sprite viewable, the icon of the clicked sprite viewable will become the `highlightedUrl` one in the style with my test. On the contrary, the icon will be changed back to the `url` one.

To do this programmatically, we can do the following:

```js
let dataVizExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.DataVisualization');

// Select a sprite viewable
dataVizExt.highlightViewables( [ spriteViewableDbId ] );
viewer.impl.invalidate( false, false, true );

// Deselect viewables
dataVizExt.clearHighlightedViewables();
```

Comment: Eason, thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I need, you saved me twice in a week, I should send a hamburger to you, thank u very much